Obtener valor de array
Quiero obtener un valor determinado de un array que obtengo con la siguiente expresión.
$resultado = $readData->getManufacturingData($producto, $fechainicial, $fechafinal);

El resultado que obtengo es el siguiente y lo que quiero obtener el el valor de NumeroFabricacion = 201.
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [NumeroFabricacion] => 201
            [Semana] => 1
            [Fecha] => 2023-01-02
            [Volumen_Inicial] => 47500
            [Volumen_Final] => 70500
            [Densidad] => 1.376
            [Riqueza] => 35.49
            [Acido] => 2.530
            [Notas] => 
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [NumeroFabricacion] => 202
            [Semana] => 1
            [Fecha] => 2023-01-03
            [Volumen_Inicial] => 47300
            [Volumen_Final] => 68600
            [Densidad] => 1.370
            [Riqueza] => 34.76
            [Acido] => 2.930
            [Notas] => 
        )
)


Pero tienes dos NumeroFabricacion, cual quieres?? el primero? el último? todos?

Sería más bien echo $resultado[0]->NumeroFabricacion; dado que es un objeto.

Cierto @A.Cedano :-)
